# How to Callback from Swift Framework to Flutter project?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I have the framework written in Swift 5 language and now i need to integrate that framework into the new flutter project and there is more number of callbacks to notify from Swift Framework to Flutter project. In that I don't know how to do that, what is the way to callback/delegate to the flutter project from Swift Framework.

Comment: IMO the linked question (How do I use a Flutter MethodChannel to invoke a method in dart code from the native swift code?) is _not_ a duplicate of this question. Well, they are and they aren't. They have similar titles (questions), but are different _issues_. The linked post is about initialization order related to callbacks. This post is much more general: how does one code a callback. ... but, this question is probably too general in nature as an SO question is supposed to be about a technical problem as opposed to please teach me how to...

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [Method channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). You can call Flutter methods from Swift code and vise versa.

iOS:

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

    private var flutterMethodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel?

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        flutterMethodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(
            name: "packageOfYourApp",
            binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger
        ) 
        flutterMethodChannel?.invokeMethod(
            "methodName",
            arguments: nil
        )
    }

}
```

Flutter:

```dart
_someMethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler((handler) async {
  if (handler.method == 'methodName') {
    // Do your logic here.
  } else {
    print('Unknown method from MethodChannel: ${handler.method}');
  }
});
```

Comment: Super! Can I ask for one more thing? What does the other side (dart) look like?

Comment: @steve, check solution again. I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome. As a concise answer to a specific question, your answer helps me and will helps others too.